# Evaluate $ 3\frac{ dy } {dx} \{ 3x\frac{ dy } {dx} - 1 \}^2 -1$ with $x,y$ functions in $t$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If
$$ x = \frac {t + 2011} {t^3} ,$$
$$ y = \frac {2011} t - \frac 2 3\log_e t, $$

then what is the value of:
$$ 3\left(\frac{ dy } {dx} \right)\left\{ 3x\Big(\frac{ dy } {dx} \Big) - 1 \right\}^2 -1$$

The answer given is $(2010)\cdot(2012)$, quite strangly independent of $t$. The hint given in the solution is $ \dfrac{ dy } {dx}  = \dfrac {t^2} 3$. I am not able to reach this point, even after doing a lot of juggling with the symbols. Please help!

Comment: $dy/dx=(dy/dt)/(dx/dt)$.

Comment: I know that and I did use it. My saying that the given answer was independent of $t$ was actually because almost all the problems I've seen in parametric differentiation so far have always contained the parameter.

Comment: If you had told us that you know that and used it, it would have saved us the trouble of me telling you something you already knew. And if you had not only told us, but showed us how you used it, someone might have found a mistake. It pays, when you ask a question, to tell people everything you know about the problem.

Comment: Actually the thing was, the working I had done was quite messy, so I thought it'd be a lot of trouble to type the whole thing. Most of the times, however, I do tell whatever attempts were made by me to solve the problem. This time I didn't - sorry! Next time it won't happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac2{t^3}-\frac{2011\cdot3}{t^4}=-\frac{2t+2011\cdot3}{t^4}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dt}= -\frac{2011}{t^2}-\frac23\frac1t=-\frac{2011\cdot3+2t}{3t^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}=\frac{t^2}3$$

Now, put the values of $\frac{dy}{dx},x$

Comment: I just gave out a loud, really loud shout - DUMB mistake! I've repeated the same mistake of not applying the chain rule properly at least a hundred times!!! Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the easy bit:

$$\cfrac {dx}{dt}= -2\cdot t^{-3} -3\cdot 2011\cdot t^{-4}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt} = -2011 \cdot t^{-2} -\frac23t^{-1}=\frac13t^2\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Now $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac {dx}{dt}}=\frac {t^2}3$$

Then we substitute just for $\frac {dy}{dx}$ to simplify and obtain the expression

$$t^2(xt^2-1)^2-1=(xt^3-t)^2-1$$

Now substitute for $x$ and factorize as the difference of two squares.